# Drawing walls - visible only one side

Tags: c#, 3d, xna

I'm creating my first 3D app in XNA and I have a problem.
I created a quad from this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464051%28XNAGameStudio.10%29.aspx
I didn't need any texture for now so I moved quadEffect definition to Initialize and left only this line:

```
quadEffect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);
```

It is displaying as white wall.

Also I am able to move my camera. It works fine but when i go behind my wall it disappears. What is causing this and how can I make it visible from both sides?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backface culling is done by default in XNA.  If you want to draw the backface of your quad, you will need to set the culling mode:

```
RasterizerState rs = new RasterizerState();
rs.CullMode = CullMode.None; 

GraphicsDevice.RasterizerState = rs;
```